# triggering a solenoid valve from batteries charged by hydroelectric system

Tags: voltage, relay, solenoid

I'm providing a slow-closing solenoid valve for a hydroelectric system in a village in the Philippines.  I need to have the normally closed valve activated to open when the batteries are drained to a certain level.

The current system (without a solenoid valve) is a mile-long pipe descending from a small pond.  During the operational season, it runs 24/7 and the system for bleeding off the produced energy keeps getting fried.  So we are thinking the solenoid would prevent that problem and decrease wear and tear on the hydro system.

I'm out of my league here and could use some ideas asap.  Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to work out where the water will go when the valve is closed.

Comment: I think they were planning on just letting the water flow down the creek, the "pond" is man-made in a creek bed.  I will have to check to see how full the pipe is as it flows through the system, because that could add tremendous weight over a mile of pipe.

Comment: +1 on what @immibis said. "mile-long pipe descending" is a huge amount of energy which needs to be handled when you turn off the flow.

Comment: I was referring to what Ty was talking about (the water continues flowing down a creek). I expect that closing the valve slowly enough will prevent the water's inertia causing any problems, but you're right @winny, I didn't think of that.

Comment: @immibis Slowly only means you will dissipate the energy over a longer time. You still need to snub away all the energy somehow. Here is a picture of my local hydropower plant. Long pipe (L) and two huge reservoirs (C) close to the lid (switch), forming a lossless or RC snubber depending on how you look at it. https://www.geocaching.com/geocache/GC33MGX_lernbo-kraftstation?guid=ce583f25-1cf3-490d-8686-980bb73d8212

Comment: We are planning to use a 1" slow-closing actuated ball valve to prevent water hammering.  The water is flowing down a 2" pipe from the pool that was dug and does travel a very long way to get to the hydro unit that charges the two batteries.  Are you thinking that the water needs a small outlet of some sort rather than backing up the pipe?  Before entering the generator, the pipe reduces to 1", which is where my friend wants to put the ball valve.  I am hoping that we can find some sort of battery charge monitor that sets off a signal to a light that can be used to actuate the valve somehow.

Comment: This is just a small set up in a very remote area where there are no vehicles of any kind due to the steepness of the mountains.  During the rainy season, the hydroelectric generator provides both 110VAC and 220VAC for the school and medical clinic.  When it is not able to operate for lack of water, then they rely on solar and generators.

Comment: the psi of the stopped pipe gets up to around 130, the valve is rated for 175

Comment: the valve runs off 12vDC and we have to figure out how to make it work when the batteries are drawn down.  It's a normally closed valve.  I think that is about it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a simple microcontroller do the job.

For ex: using an 'if' function using two variables as so would help

Comment: Are you aware of a commercially-available microcontroller that would be user-friendly for my friends in the mountains of Palawan that could perform this function?  It would need to be connected in some way to a battery charge monitor, no?  Fortunately, they are more familiar with electronics than I, but can't get their hands on much in their remote area.  So I scrounge stuff up and ship it to them with funds we've raised for their project.  Thanks for your answer, by the way.

Comment: perhaps it would be better if I asked for a 2 or 3 companies that are well-known for items that would meet my need

Comment: use an arduino knockoff, it would be very cheap, and easy get things done